# Wrong photo src in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I use ckeditor 5 to record product descriptions.

This is my **client** code:

```
class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor(loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
                this._sendRequest(file);
            }));
    }
    abort() {
        if (this.xhr) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Products/UploadFileDescription', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }
    _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;
        xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
        xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;
            if (!response || response.error) {
                return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
            }
            resolve({
                default: response.Result
            });
        });
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    _sendRequest(file) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);
        this.xhr.send(data);
    }
}
function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
    editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
        return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
    };
}
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin],
    })
    .then(editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

And this is my **server** side code for saving images:

```
    [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Products/UploadFileDescription")]
        public IActionResult UploadFileDescription(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/products/descriptionFiles", fileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                        return Json(new { url = filePath });
                    }
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult("Error");
        }
```

My photo is saved correctly in the path I saved, but the photo's address is wrong and that's why the photos are not displayed in the product description. For example:
[image]

I would appreciate any advise.